# Based on these configuration attribute values need to select the product with same values

Tags: cpq

I have implemented three fields within the product interface, specifically for indicating the device type, engine type, and model year selection. Additionally, I have established a configuration attribute encompassing these three fields. Upon selecting the values within this configuration attribute, my objective is to retrieve products that correspond exclusively to these specified values. I am trying to achieve this using the selection rule not getting the exact solution.

For instance, if I have selected "Audi" as the device type, "Detroit" as the engine type, and "2020" as the model year, I anticipate obtaining only those products that align with this specific combination. How can I effectively achieve this functionality? Any assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.
[image: below is the image of attributes]
[image: image of the field in product]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather using the filter functionality to show the relevant products.

The problem with using configuration attributes together with product rules is that every product that needs to show for the given configuration attribute selection, needs to be explicitly defined in its own action inside the product rule.

You can find the Salesforce help files on how to setup a custom action [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_custom_actions.htm&type=5)

Basically you should:

1. Create a custom action similar to `Add Products`
2. Name it something like `Add Vehicles`
3. Create Search Filters for `Device Type`, `Model Type` and `Model Year`
4. You can even add a hidden filter on product family to only show a certain product family (in your screenshot is it `Hardware`, but I would imagine it would be something like `Vehicles` for your use case)

Now when you want to add a vehicle, you select `Add Vehicle` and enter the filter criteria to show all the relevant products.

Good luck!